# Access to Local Storage of current page using Chrome Extension Manifest Version 3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm migrating from manifest version 2 to version 3 and one of the functions I used to have to access the local storage of the current page was using this script:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:'JSON.stringify(localStorage)'},function(result) {});
```

From the page these are the values I need to access:

[image]

What would be the recommendation in order to pull all keys?

Comment: Use chrome.scripting.executeScript with `func: ()=>JSON.stringify(localStorage)`, see the documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm that helped me to access it, Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access to the values using this scrip on the popup.js file.

```
function getLocalStorage(){
     return  JSON.stringify(localStorage);
 }

chrome.scripting.executeScript({
target: { tabId: currentTab}, // you can get the Tab id using chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {});
    func: getLocalStorage,
},
(injectionResults) => {
    console.log('storage response: '+injectionResults[0].result); 
});
```

Hope this helps.